# How to know if the data on the server is newer than the data on the device, or vice versa?

Tags: android, offline-caching, android-syncadapter

I have been trying to implement SyncAdapter to **sync** data between client(android device) and server using sqlite.The same data will be shared between different devices.

**On Update:**
As soon as a particular record is updated on one client device it will be pushed to the server. At that moment the updated record should also be synced from the server to other connected devices.

Now, when we send sync request from other connected devices, what is the best way to know which record get updated on the server?

Comment: The client application should pull the updated records and new records only not the complete table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do to achieve this:

- First, consider using timestamps. Here is how that could work;
- In your database table (remotely), have a column **updated_at** which as soon as you sync your fresh data up, you should set a new timestamp for it.
- In your android code, you can simply store **lastSyncTime** in your preferences then compare with what you get from your server column.

You can easily pull the value from an endpoint */last_sync/* to see if the sync_time has changed.

By comparing the two timestamps, you can then decide as to whether you want to sync down new data or keep the old until the new ones are synced.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. But if there are thousands of record in the table(remote server) we have to compare the timestamp thousand times. This comparison will increase as the number of record increases in the server. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: If you run a sql statement/query with something like "where updated_at > lastSync, that should do it.